# Cómo crear un script generador de seriales

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentando crear un generador de seriales de 5 filas de 4 numeros cada una, mezclados con numeros y letras, es decir así:
**F452-4B85-6985-6W87-4H87** ya he buscado en la web y no aparece ningún resultado. me interesa saber cómo puedo crear este generador implementando javascript o jquery y que este mismo vaya creando seriales ilimitadamente.

```html
<!-- por ahora solo tengo el boton -->
<button>Generar serial</button>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) , también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. Tu pregunta es muy corta y de baja calidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto implica varias tareas, esencialmente, obtener un caracter de manera pseudoaleatoria dentro de un rango de valores.

Para nuestro caso los valores posibles los ponemos en una variable.

```
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
```

para obtener el caracter en cierta posición usamos el método `charAt` de String.

para obtener un índice entero aleatorio dentro de un rango usamos matemáticas básicas:

Sea *p* una pseudo-matriz de tamaño *l* y dada una función *charAt* para obtener el elemento i-ésimo. Siendo x un valor aleatorio que viene en el rango [0..1] en R+.

Para obtener un elemento *y* en el espacio de valores definido por *p* definimos la función indiceValido como:

[image: el piso de x por l]

y para obtener un elemento válido en la pseudo-matriz solamente hay que usarlo

[image: matriz con el índice referenciado]

```
function getARandomOneInRange() {
  return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
```

Lo siguiente que yo haría sería obtener cada bloque, es decir cuatro caracteres aleatorios por vez. O como está de moda eso de lo funcional, podríamos decir que la función que hicimos es pura y por agregación podemos componerla para a partir del monoide obtener una mónada y blah blah. Igual de momento esto no es taa relevante ya que no usaremos hilos ni nada de esas cosas divertidas que en JS apenas pocos usan.

```
function getRandomFour() {
  return getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange();
}
```

Y finalmente unirlos con un template solamente por el hecho de que se ve más bonito que una concatenación de la vieja escuela.

```
var serial = `${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}`;
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

  function getARandomOneInRange() {
    return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  function getRandomFour() {
    return getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange() + getARandomOneInRange();
  }

  $('#btnSerial').click(function() {
    var serial = `${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}-${getRandomFour()}`;
    $('#txtSerial').val(serial);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- por ahora solo tengo el boton -->
<button id="btnSerial">Generar serial</button>
<label>Serial:</label>
<input id="txtSerial" type="text" />
```

Comment: Gracias maestro. existe posibilidad de crear un historial de codigos generados?

Comment: Hola @RuslanLópez, me llamó sobremanera la atención cuando dices: ***no usaremos hilos ni nada de esas cosas divertidas que en JS apenas pocos usan***. ¿Podrías mostrarme cómo usar hilos en JS? Y no me refiero a WebWorkers, digamos que en Node por ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: @CODEADICTO puedes agregar lso seriales generados en la estructura de datos que gustes, sino recuero en JS más moderno ya se puede usar aunque precariamente map para que tu estructura te mantenga libre de duplicados por tí, o si prefieres un arrelgo con clave-valor debería de bastar.

Comment: @MauricioContreras una aplicación NodeJS corre en un único hilo, lo único en que usa varios hilos es para manipulación de archivos y eso lo hace internamente. Si te interesa realmente programación multihilos como tal en NodeJS además de estudiar los WebWorkers para empezar te recomiendo el módulo clusters, y no dudes en hacer tu propia pregunta, seguro hay gente más especializada en esos temas.

Comment: @RuslanLópez muchas gracias por la info. Hace tiempo le había dado un vistazo muy por encima, tanto que no lo relacioné con multihilos al momento. Hasta ahora no lo había necesitado, pero creo que le daré una buena repasada. De verdad, mill gracias.